# ¿Cómo poner un valor inicial en un ModelForm ModelChoiceField con un widget RadioSelect en Django?

Tags: python, django

Mi objetivo es que salga una opción ya seleccionada, pero a pesar de haber encontrado muchas soluciones en internet, no me funciona ninguna.

Este es mi modelo:

```
class ModelOpciones(models.Model):
    opciones = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.opciones
```

Este es mi formulario:

```
class OpcionesForm(forms.Form):
    Campo_Opciones = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = ModelOpciones.objects.none(), widget=forms.RadioSelect, empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = kwargs.pop('field1_qs')
        super(OpcionesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Campo_Opciones'].queryset = qs
```

y aquí es como lo relleno en la vista:

```
form2 = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None, field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all())
```

---

**He probado:**

---

**1º** Añadir un valor por defecto en la construcción de form2 en la vista:

```
form2 = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None, field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all(), default = ModelOpciones.objects.first())
```

pero recibo este error:

```
TypeError at /AV/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/AV/
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\VenvProyecto\AV_ESI\ESI_App\forms.py in __init__, line 22
```

---

**2º** Añadir un valor por defecto pero usando "initial":

```
form2 = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None, field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all(), initial = {'Campo_Opciones': ModelOpciones.objects.first()})
```

No hubo errores, pero tampoco dió resultado.

---

**3º** Lo mismo pero accediendo al pk:

```
form2 = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None, field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all(), initial = {'Campo_Opciones': ModelOpciones.objects.first().pk})
```

Sin resultados.

---

**4º** Leí que por lo visto "request.POST" elimina la información de valor inicial y una solución podría ser esta...:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form2 = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None, field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all())
else:
    form2 = OpcionesForm(field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all(), initial = {'Campo_Opciones': ModelOpciones.objects.first()})
```

dejando el código del formulario igual --> Sin resultados

---

**5º** ...y otra opción podría ser esta:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form2 = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None, field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all())
else:
    form2 = OpcionesForm(field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all())
```

y en el formulario:

```
    class OpcionesForm(forms.Form):
        Campo_Opciones = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = ModelOpciones.objects.none(), widget=forms.RadioSelect, empty_label=None, initial = {'Campo_Opciones': ModelOpciones.objects.first()})
```

Sin resultados.

---

**6º** He probado (a la desesperada) otras combinaciones de esas opciones en la definición del formulario y en el modelo, pero de una forma o de otra no ha funcionado.

¿Ha habido algo que no he tenido en cuenta? Por favor, agradecería algunas ideas.

un saludo:
Miguel.

Comment: ¿En tu ForeignKey `ModelOpciones` tienes un `default=` asignado en el modelo?

Comment: ¿Te refieres aquí: `class ModelOpciones(models.Model):
    opciones = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.opciones` ?  ¿Como atriburo de `opciones` o un nuevo atributo de la clase? ¿Sería `default = 0`?

Comment: Eso es. Puede que te funcione si lo defines como:
    `class ModelOpciones(models.Model):
        models.CharField(max_length=300, default="default_value")`

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido, le dí a "enter" sin querer y no me dio tiempo a editar la pregunta. El problema es que ese "default_value" quiero que sea la primera opción por ejemplo, pero a cada consulta cambia.

Comment: Necesitas que, en función de algo, cambie el valor que aparece seleccionado, ¿no?

Comment: Básicamente necesito que en el RadioSelect aparezca cualquier opción seleccionada, me da igual que sea la primera o cualquier otra

Comment: ¿En tu `OpcionesForm` has indicado `class Meta: model =  ModelOpciones`? Yo creo que incluyendo eso y, además, poniendo el `default=` en las opciones del ModelOpciones debería funcionar.

Comment: ¿Quieres que traslademos esta conversación al chat? He probado lo que me dices, con default = 0 en el modelo, he puesto 0 porque no sé como indicar que sea la primera opción. Aún así no ha funcionado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55277/discussion-between-andruten-and-miguelw).

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque fue resuelto en el chat, sin que se publicara una respuesta.